# How do I share Monaca Cloud IDE code?

Tags: cordova, share, monaca

Clicking on "Share" shows a message in Chinese letters. Is it a message telling me something or a "link" that I should use somehow? Or just a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are sorry about the Japanese message. We are fixing it now. 
This message is about how you don't have enough privilege to share the project. For example, you may try to assign a user as a Developer but that user doesn't have a valid subscription for that. Please refer to our [Pricing page](https://monaca.io/pricing-detail.html).